# Need an easy way to change my string into an integer in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string like this:

```
var myString = "025"
```

Is there an easy way to change this to a number?

Comment: -1. At least try to search first.

Comment: The *easiest* way, given your sample, is to remove the quotation marks around 025.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int myNumber = int.Parse(myString);
```

Note that this will throw an exception if myString cannot be converted to an int. You can use TryParse instead that is safer

```
int myNumber
if( int.TryParse(myString, out myNumber){
  //conversion ok, and myNumber now contains the int
}else{
  //conversion failed. myNumber will now be 0.
}
```

Comment: why int.Parse not Convert.Toint32(string);

Comment: Thanks very much for your good answer. There are cases where my string might not be a number so your example helps. I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: @rahularyansharma - I think it looks a lot cleaner to use int.Parse. If you check what `Convert.ToInt32(string)` does it is to check if the argument is null. If it is, return 0, else it calls `int.Parse` directly itself.

Comment: @ Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen then it will be better to call Convert.ToInt32(string) because its have self error handling as you done in your answer explicitly by using try and catch

Comment: @rahularyansharma - No error handling. You still need to check for illegal strings, and will get an FormatException if it does not match. It just checks for null. I would usually prefer TryParse, if I don't want it to blow up if the string is not an int. This is the implementation of Convert.ToInt32(string): `public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}`. Please excuse the formatting in the comment.

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen how u format in comment the code ?// and thanks buddy giving a positive response

Comment: @rahularyansharma - You can't It get on a single line regardless. But you can at least add hyphens to make it stand out a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInt = Int32.Parse(myString);
```

Although for these kind of questions, I think reading a book and discovering the language would do some good.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
string str = "123";
int value = int.MinValue;

if(int.TryParse(str, out value))
 MessageBox.Show("Successfully parsed");
else
   MessageBox.Show("Parsing failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it is possible to use:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32("myString");
```

Comment: I simply dont understand why people downvote an answer without leaving comment.

Comment: @Abdul Probably because the sample code is incorrect - "myString" is not convertible to a number.

Comment: @ Winston Smith yeah definitely, but leaving comment is a better option so that the answerer might know the problem in his code.